# Using [] square brackets as part of a parameter in $resource GET call to API in Angular is not working

Tags: angularjs, api, http, parameters

I am trying trying to GET user data from an ajax-localized REST api that wants parameters like so:

```
/api/activity?filter[user_id]=1
```

I have a factory set up with query parameters like so:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Activity',function($resource){
        return $resource(ajaxInfo.api_url+'activity',
        { // Query parameters
            filter: {
                '[user_id]': '@userId'
            }, 
        }, 
        {
            'query':{
                method:'GET',
                headers: {
                    'X-WP-Nonce': ajaxInfo.nonce
                },
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    })
```

I'm console.logging it in a template like so:

```
$scope.userOne = Activity.query({userId:1});
console.log($scope.userOne)
```

It's returning

```
http:site.dev/api/activity?filter=%7B%22%5Buser_id%5D%22:%22@userId%22%7D&userId=1".
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the query parameters as `{ 'filter[user_id]' : '@userId' }`?

Comment: Now I'm getting `activity?filter=%7B%22filter%5Buser_id%5D%22:%22@userId%22%7D&userId=1".`

Comment: I mean: `return $resource(ajaxInfo.api_url+'activity', { 'filter[user_id]' : '@userId' }, { 'query': ......`

Comment: Tried it and it looks like it stripped out the whole query and gives me this: /activity?userId=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix this:

I created a factory called "CurrentUser" this factory basically returns the current user's object from an api.

Then I created a controller that passed the parameters to the Activity factory when I wanted to filter the activity by that user id.

```
$scope.userInfo = function(){
    //call the CurrentUser and see if it's available and return it as u
    CurrentUser.instance().then(function(u) {
        //now query the activity factory and pass the filter as a string along with the user id as u.id
        Activity.query({'filter[user_id]':u.id}, function(res){
            $scope.userOne = res ;
            console.log($scope.userOne);
        });
    })

};
$scope.userInfo();
```